# Organizar posições de um vetor

Tags: java, array

- Preciso criar dois vetores, com 3 elementos cada e números reais
- Depois copiar esses valores para um novo vetor com 6 elementos
- Os 3 primeiros valores devem ser do vetor que tiver o maior valor de somatória

Exemplo:

```
vetor1 [2.3, 4.7, 1.4], soma resulta em 8.4
vetor2 [1.6, 6.2, 3.5], soma resulta em 11.3
vetor3 [1.6, 6.2, 3.5, 2.3, 4.7, 1.4]
```

Meu código:

```
public class exer6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] vetor1 = {4.3, 2.5, 4.7};
        double[] vetor2 = {5.7, 5.8, 3.7};
        double[] vetor3 = new double[6];
        double soma1 = 0, soma2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < vetor1.length; i++) {
            soma1+=vetor1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor2.length; i++) {
            soma2+=vetor2[i];
        }
        if (soma1 > soma2) {
            soma1 = vetor3.length;
            soma2 = vetor3.length;
        } else {
            soma2 = vetor3.length;
            soma1 = vetor3.length;
        }
        System.out.println(vetor3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: começei a programar recentemente, e então, tente não dar risada da minha lógica.

Comment: Se os vetores tem o mesmo tamanho, da pra fazer a somatoria com um laço apenas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **Java** oferece diferentes formas para copiar o conteúdo de um `array` para outro:

1. Implementando um laço com o comando **for**
2. Utilizando o método **clone**
3. Utilizando **System.arraycopy**
4. Utilizando **Arrays.copyOf**

A estratégia mais adequada neste casso é o **`arraycopy`** em que você pode definir exatamente as posições que você quer copiar com apenas uma linha, com o melhor desempenho e sem a necessidade de importar nenhuma biblioteca adicional, ou seja, fácil e eficiente.

```
public class Exercicio6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float somaV1 = 0, somaV2 = 0;
    float[] vetor1 = {4.3f, 2.5f, 4.7f};
    float[] vetor2 = {5.7f, 5.8f, 3.7f};

    for(int i = 0; i < vetor1.length; i++) {
      somaV1 += vetor1[i];
      somaV2 += vetor2[i];
    }

    System.out.print("Vetor 1 [" + vetor1[0] + ", " + vetor1[1]);
    System.out.println(", " + vetor1[2] + "] Soma = " + somaV1);
    System.out.print("Vetor 2 [" + vetor2[0] + ", " + vetor2[1]);
    System.out.println(", " + vetor2[2] + "] Soma = " + somaV2);

    float[] vetor3 = new float[6];

    if (somaV1 > somaV2) {
      System.arraycopy(vetor1, 0, vetor3, 0, vetor1.length);
      System.arraycopy(vetor2, 0, vetor3, 3, vetor2.length);
      System.out.println("\nVetor 1 com maior soma, resultado final:\n");
      System.out.print("Vetor 3 [" + vetor3[0] + ", " + vetor3[1] + ", " + vetor3[2]);
      System.out.print(", " + vetor3[3] + ", " + vetor3[4] + ", " + vetor3[5] + "]");
    } else {
      System.arraycopy(vetor2, 0, vetor3, 0, vetor2.length);
      System.arraycopy(vetor1, 0, vetor3, 3, vetor1.length);
      System.out.print("\nVetor 2 com maior soma, resultado final:\n");
      System.out.print("Vetor 3 [" + vetor3[0] + ", " + vetor3[1] + ", " + vetor3[2]);
      System.out.print(", " + vetor3[3] + ", " + vetor3[4] + ", " + vetor3[5] + "]");
    }
  }
}
```

Execute o código online: http://ideone.com/g6gKLR

A única coisa que pode ser mais estranho na utilização do `arraycopy` são os parâmetros que podem confundi-lo, porém abaixo está uma breve explicação do que significa cada um na ordem em que eles são passados:

1. `Object objetoQueSeraCopiado`
2. `int posicaoInicialObjetoQueSeraCopiado`
3. `Object objetoDestino`
4. `int posicaoObjetoDestino`
5. `int tamanhoObjetoCopiado`

Utilizado no exemplo:

```
System.arraycopy(vetor1, 0, vetor3, 0, vetor1.length);
```

O **vetor1** será copiado, a partir da posição **zero**, para o **vetor3**, começando na posição **zero**, fazendo uma cópia tamanho total (***length***) do **vetor1**.

```
System.arraycopy(vetor2, 0, vetor3, 3, vetor2.length);
```

O **vetor2** será copiado, a partir da posição **zero**, para o **vetor3**, começando na posição **três**, fazendo uma cópia tamanho total (***length***) do **vetor2**.

---

Para copiar vetores utilizando **`for`**:

```
//Criando um vetorB do mesmo tamanho do vetorA
int [] vetorB = new int[vetorA.length];

//O vetorB recebe todos os dados do vetorA
for (int i=0; i < vetorA.length; i++) {
    vetorB[i] = vetorA[i];
}
//Exibe os dados do vetorB copiados do vetorA
for (int i=0; i < vetorB.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("vetorB[" + i + "] = " + vetorB[i]);
}
```

---

Para fazer uma cópia de vetor através do método nativo **`clone()`** é muito simples:

```
int [] vetorB = vetorA.clone();
```

---

Através da biblioteca **java.util.Arrays** é possível utilizar o **`copyOf`**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int [] vetorB = Arrays.copyOf(vetorA, vetorA.length);
```

---

**Mais informações:**

- http://www.devmedia.com.br/copiando-o-conteudo-de-um-array-em-java/26732

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar o método [`arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) após fazer a verificação de qual soma é maior. Para utilizar o método é preciso especificar alguns parâmetros, conforme indicado [na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

> ```
> public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int
> destPos, int length)
> ```

Os argumentos `src` e `dest` representam os vetores origem e destino, respectivamente. O argumento `srcPos` é a posição inicial no *array* origem. O argumento `destPos` é a posição inicial no *array* destino. Por fim, `length` é utilizado para especificarmos o número de elementos que serão copiados.

Veja como ficaria:

```
 if (soma1 > soma2) {

     System.arraycopy(vector1, 0, vector3, 0, vector1.length);
     System.arraycopy(vector1, 0, vector3, vector1.length, vector2.length);

 } else {

     System.arraycopy(vector2, 0, vector3, 0, vector2.length);
     System.arraycopy(vector2, 0, vector3, vector2.length, vector1.length);
 }
```

Veja funcionando aqui [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/Oi3oCt).

Comment: Seria interessante explicar o que está acontecendo nesse código, por se tratar de um método meio incomum de se utlizar(ao menos pra mim é bem incomum, pro OP que está começando pode ser mais ainda)

Comment: @diegofm sim, senhor! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double[] vetor1 = new double[]{2.3, 4.7, 1.4};
        double[] vetor2 = new double[]{1.6, 6.2, 3.5};
        double[] vetor3 = new double[vetor1.length+vetor2.length];
        double soma1, soma2;
        int i;

        //Calcular a soma de cada vetor
        soma1 = soma2 = 0.0;
        for(i=0; i < vetor1.length; ++i)
            soma1 += vetor1[i];
        for(i=0; i < vetor2.length; ++i)
            soma2 += vetor2[i];

        //Verificar se os vetores estão na ordem pretendida
        if (soma2 > soma1)
        {
            //Trocar os vetores, pois estão ao contrário
            double[] vetorTmp = vetor1;
            vetor1 = vetor2;
            vetor2 = vetorTmp;
        }

        //Copiar o vetor1 para as primeiras posições do vetor3
        for(i=0; i<vetor1.length; ++i)
            vetor3[i] = vetor1[i];
        //Copiar o vetor2 para as últimas posições do vetor3
        for(i=0; i<vetor2.length; ++i)
            vetor3[i+vetor1.length] = vetor2[i];
        //Imprimir o vetor na consola
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vetor3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use o método sort(),
No caso do Java para usa-lo importe a lib java.util.Arrays.

Arrays.sort(Array);

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initializing unsorted int array
        double myArr[] = {1.6, 6.2, 3.5, 2.3, 4.7, 1.4};

        // let us print all the elements available in list
        for (double number : myArr) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }

        // sorting array
        Arrays.sort(myArr);

        // let us print all the elements available in list
        System.out.println("The sorted double array is:");
        for (double number : myArr) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Comment: Não vejo como isso resolve o problema da pergunta.